# Why can't xcode find the kotlinmultiplatformshared module? (Even though it builds successfully)

Tags: xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

[image][image]I went through the process of adding a kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule called kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule through android studio and then I git cloned an existing iOS project. I followed the xcode related steps mentioned here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/multiplatform-integrate-in-existing-app.html#enjoy-the-results-update-the-logic-only-once

Then I built everything and it worked, but when I open the ios project's xcworkspace file in xcode, everything builds successfully, but this error remains. I am using xcode 14.3

I thought that maybe i could try import Kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule instead of import kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule. But case sensitivity does not seem to be the issue. I have used regular framework option on Android Studio.

Edit: I think xcode 14.3 might be the issue as shown here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-compatibility-guide.html#changes-in-gradle-input-and-output-compile-tasks

Comment: I think the issue might just be that xcode is version 14.3 and kotlin is 1.9.20. jetbrains suggests using xcode 15.